# AppScript updates every row state after sending email

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

The following appscript tries to send an email for each row where "ESTADO" is not "ENVIADO" and then updating "ESTADO" with "ENVIADO" for every email sent.

```
function seguimientosemail() {

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("SeguimientoDNI2");
var range = sheet.getRange("A2:D");
var UserData = range.getValues();

for (i in UserData) {
var row = UserData[i];
var cliente = row[0];
var tracking = row[1];
var email = row[2];
var estado = row[3];

if (estado != "ENVIADO" && estado != "ESTADO" && email != ""){
MailApp.sendEmail(row[2], "Custom mail", "Hello " + cliente + ", This is an email report of your tracking code. Your tracking is " + tracking);

   sheet.getRange(i,4).setValue("ENVIADO");
   SpreadsheetApp.flush();
}
}
}
```

Given this example table

```
CLIENTE TRACKINGPARACOPIAR  EMAIL   ESTADO
Gladis Ortiz.   135081342   email1@gmail.com    ENVIADO
María Soledad Hernandez     135081360   email2@gmail.com    
Cristina Orozco 135081387   email3@gmail.com
```

It updates like this:

```
CLIENTE TRACKINGPARACOPIAR  EMAIL   ENVIADO
Gladis Ortiz.   135081342   email1@gmail.com    ENVIADO
María Soledad Hernandez     135081360   email2@gmail.com    
Cristina Orozco 135081387   email3@gmail.com
```

But expected output is this:

```
CLIENTE TRACKINGPARACOPIAR  EMAIL   ESTADO
Gladis Ortiz.   135081342   email1@gmail.com    ENVIADO
María Soledad Hernandez     135081360   email2@gmail.com ENVIADO
Cristina Orozco 135081387   email3@gmail.com ENVIADO
```

I tried to do

```
sheet.getRange(i+1,4).setValue("ENVIADO");
```

but it didnt work. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you start from the **second** row of the sheet: `getRange("A2:D")`, you should add `2` in the `getRange` argument:

```
sheet.getRange(i+2,4).setValue("ENVIADO");
```

Don't forget that array index in JavaScript always starts with **zero**. If `A2` (second row) corresponds to the first element-row (`0`) of the `UserData` array, then you need to add `2` to match them.

---

**Solution:**

```
function seguimientosemail() {

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("SeguimientoDNI2");
var sheet_size=sheet.getRange('A:A').getValues().filter(String).length +1;
var range = sheet.getRange("A2:D"+sheet_size);
var UserData = range.getValues();


for (let i=0; i<UserData.length;i++) {
var row = UserData[i];
var cliente = row[0];
var tracking = row[1];
var email = row[2];
var estado = row[3];

if (estado != "ENVIADO" && estado != "ESTADO" && email != ""){
MailApp.sendEmail(row[2], "Custom mail", "Hello " + cliente + ", This is an email report of your tracking code. Your tracking is " + tracking);

   sheet.getRange(i+2,4).setValue("ENVIADO");
   SpreadsheetApp.flush();
}
}
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work the output for the first email sent is correct for the second one the ENVIADO value is being added way below in the table

Comment: @sebas I updated my answer. Please try again my new solution. If this also does not work, can you please share a sample file with us? Remove all the sensitive information. This will help us reproduce the issue and therefore resolve it.

Comment: I don't see what you changed on your code but here is a test sheet https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1zpaunFUvwD2AF0t6JvvPQIRJ3UMtVkgR7Ig40-_S_Z4/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @sebas I am sure the issue now it is you have rows filled in the bottom of your sheet. Please remove them. But anyway, I just updated my code again. Try please again.